# The statement break is not breaking my while loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to programming. I am learning python. I am trying to solve a problem to develop my coding skill.
Problem link: [UVa 299 Train Swapping](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=235)

I have written a code to solve the problem.

My code:

```
t = int(input())
for i in range(t):
    value = int(input())
    numbers = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
    count = 0
    while True:
        for item in range(len(numbers) - 1):
            if numbers[item] > numbers[item + 1]:
                count = count + 1
                numbers[item], numbers[item + 1] = numbers[item + 1], numbers[item]
        counter = 0
        for x in range(len(numbers) - 1):
            if numbers[x] < numbers[x + 1]:
                counter = counter + 1
        if counter == len(numbers):
            break
    print(count)
```

Though I have use `break` to break the while loop but the loop is not breaking.

Please help me to break the loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `for item in range(len(numbers) - 1):` is rather verbose (probably required in VBA) and is not required for python. I'd recommend you to use this instead `for i, j in zip(numbers,numbers[1:]):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `x` only ranged from `0` to `len(numbers) - 1`, `counter` cannot be equal to `len(numbers)` because even if everytime in the `for x in range(len(numbers) - 1)` loop `counter` increased by 1, the maximum it can get is still `len(numbers) - 1`. So change your `if` statement to

```
        if counter == len(numbers) - 1:
            break
```

And you'll be fine.